# How would you form the comparative of an adjective?

Tags: grammar, help, form

How do you express the comparative form of an adjective in Japanese? (e.g. lower, higher, taller)

Comment: As described in @[Metch](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/51375/)'s answer, note that **there is no "comparative form of an adjective" in Japanese.**  While English has distinct adjective forms for "base adjective" (like _red_), "comparative" (like _red**der**_), and "superlative" (like _red**dest**_), Japanese just has the same form for all three (like 赤【あか】い), and instead uses syntax and other words to indicate comparisons and degree.

Answer (score 3):

「Aは　Bより　adjです」means "A is more (adj) than B".

For example:

Aさんは　Bさんより　わかいです。

A is younger than B.

Comment: I think the structure より+adjective without B is also worth a mention. Actually that might more directly answer OP's question.

Comment: @EddieKal I'm intrigued. How do you use より without the noun to which it attaches?

Comment: @user3856370 より奇麗な環境

Comment: @EddieKal Ah, I see what you mean now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am reviewing this point (I find it difficult) in my textbook.  It gives a more elaborate pattern.

「Aのほうが Bより adj です。」 "A is more (adj) than B."

Aさんのほうが　Bさんより　わかいです。

A is younger than B.

My textbook also notes that in common speech, the reverse order often is used.

「Bより Aのほうが adj です。」